# Half screen page control IOS

Tags: ios

The drawing UI in IOS9 note app has a page control section on the bottom to choose colour (As shown in the attached image). I was wondering how can that be implemented? Does it use collection view at all?

[image: IOS 9 NOTE APP DRAWING UI]

Answer (score 0):

You can implement it either by using collection view with paging enabled and add UIPageControl , or by using UIPageViewController embedded in UIContainerView which can be resized and placed anywhere inside your view controller.